# Navigation rule not firing

Tags: jsf, navigation, primefaces

I have a navigation rule that looks like this:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>forgotPwd</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.jsf</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>pass</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login/pwdresetcomplete.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

So I do this to trigger the navigation rule:

- Navigate to `/login/forgotpwd.jsf?uuid=fed8b3f7-ed33-4941-8306-3d2afbb8d1d0`

This page has the following form:

```
<h:form id="resetForm">
<!-- Omitting the login fields --> 
    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="resetPassword" value="Save" styleClass="btn small" action="#{registration.resetPassword}" >
        <f:param name="uuid" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestParameterMap.uuid}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

(Takes the uuid passed as a query string parameter, and will call the registration.resetPassword function.)

Here is the registration.resetPassword java code:

(Details omitted for brevity)

```
public String resetPassword() {
  // If good
  return "pass";
  // If bad
  return "fail"
}
```

Problem: When it returns "pass", the navigation rule is not firing. It goes back to /login/forgotpwd.jsf instead of /login/pwdresetcomplete.jsf

Is this because it has the UUID parameter appended to it? Why is my navigation not firing?

Is there some log4j logging that I can trigger to see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<from-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.jsf</from-view-id>
```

The `from-view-id` must be the view ID, not the virtual URL. So, it should not contain `.jsf` extension.

```
<from-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.xhtml</from-view-id>
```

---

By the way, request parameters are in the view available by `#{param}`. This saves some characters as compared to `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestParameterMap}`.

```
<f:param name="uuid" value="#{param.uuid}" />
```

See also [implicit objects in EL](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects). Another by the way, it's not exactly clear which JSF version you're using, but since JSF 2.0 (which I guess you're using as you're on Facelets already) you don't need the navigation case XML hell anymore. You can just return the (relative and/or extension-less) `to-view-id` directly from the action method.

```
public String resetPassword() {
  // If good
  return "pwdresetcomplete";
  // If bad
  return "forgotpwd"
}
```

This way you can get rid of the whole `<navigation-rule>`. See also [implicit navigation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation).

Comment: I had been wondering if they had figured that out yet. Yes I am on JSF 2.0. That's awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added these two rules... now it works. Not sure which one did it but using the from-action made it a lot more happy.

```
<navigation-rule>
        <display-name>forgotPwd</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{registration.resetPassword}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>pass</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/pwdresetcomplete.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{registration.resetPassword}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>forgotPwd</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.jsf</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{registration.resetPassword}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>pass</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/pwdresetcomplete.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{registration.resetPassword}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login/forgotpwd.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```